# Numpy Random Choice with Non-regular Array Size

Tags: numpy, random

I'm making an array of sums of random choices from a negative binomial distribution (nbd), with each sum being of non-regular length. Right now I implement it as follows:

```
import numpy
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()

nbd = rng.negative_binomial(1, 0.5, int(1e6))
gmc = [12, 35, 4, 67, 2]
n_pp = np.empty(len(gmc))
for i in range(len(gmc)):
    n_pp[i] = np.sum(rng.choice(nbd, gmc[i]))
```

This works, but when I perform it over my actual data it's very slow (gmc is of dimension 1e6), and I would like to vary this for multiple values of n and p in the nbd (in this example they're set to 1 and 0.5, respectively).

I'd like to work out a pythonic way to do this which eliminates the loop, but I'm not sure it's possible. I want to keep default_rng for the better random generation than the older way of doing it (np.random.choice), if possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you're sampling from a large, previously-generated sample each iteration instead of making a new `negative_binomial` call each time?

Comment: Yeah, as the answer below shows, I should be approaching this differently. I thought making a large sample base would speed things up as it's a one time generation, but this (obviously) doesn't leverage broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of the sum of `m` samples from the negative binomial distribution with parameters `(n, p)` is the negative binomial distribution with parameters `(m*n, p)`.  So instead of summing random selections from a large, precomputed sample of `negative_binomial(1, 0.5)`, you can generate your result directly with `negative_binomial(gmc, 0.5)`:

```
In [68]: gmc = [12, 35, 4, 67, 2]

In [69]: npp = rng.negative_binomial(gmc, 0.5)

In [70]: npp
Out[70]: array([ 9, 34,  1, 72,  7])
```

(The `negative_binomial` method will broadcast its inputs, so we can pass `gmc` as an argument to generate all the samples with one call.)

More generally, if you want to vary the `n` that is used to generate `nbd`, you would multiply that `n` by the corresponding element in `gmc` and pass the product to `rng.negative_binomial`.

Comment: I did it my unnecessary loop way and this way and compared histograms, and this works a treat. I'll have to look at the math underlying it a bit more to be sure I get it, but this appears to do the trick. Thanks!